# Getting Error. java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected 'configure' key: 'afterScenario'

Tags: karate

here is a similar code that im usein

```
Feature: Create a company instance

Background: Creating the company instance in background
* url baseUrl
* def login = call read('classpath:blackbook/common/getToken.feature')
* def newCI = call read('../endpoints/create_companyinstance.feature')
* def id = newCI.response.data.id
* configure afterScenario =
"""
function(){
var ciID = karate.get('id');
console.log(ciID);
}
"""
```

After that i will run it. and the login call and newCI call runs fine but then i will get the following error

```
[ERROR] Scenario: Doing a get call and then some verifications  Time 
elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected 'configure' key: 
'afterScenario'
```

Please forgive noobness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jawad - apologies as I am responsible for prematurely adding documentation for un-released features.

"After hooks" is available in `0.7.0.RC2` - it would be great if you can try that and confirm if it looks good. Even though it is a "release candidate" - as the dev of Karate, I can confirm it should be good for use - and you will not have any breaking changes when "final" arrives (soon).

Comment: I suppose that the way to do that is update it in the pom?

i will try it out and inform you.